# How to prompt for input?

Tags: python-2.7

I'm new to python. how to prompt for input? I'm using python 2.7.
I tried with the following in normal mode. but it does't prompt.

the code is:

```
first =  raw_input("print any string: ")
print first
```

Please help with this....
Thanks!

Comment: `raw_input` should prompt. Do you have that following print statement on the same line like in your example? That needs to be on a separate line

Comment: are you running in a script or REPL?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
age = raw_input("How old are you? ")
height = raw_input("How tall are you? ")
weight = raw_input("How much do you weigh? ")

print "So, you're %r old, %r tall and %r heavy." % (
    age, height, weight)
```

and read this link(thats where i got the example)
http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex12.html

Answer (score 0):

your code above works on my machine. Are you running it as?:

```
python program.py
```

If you want a number, remember to cast it:

```
x = int(raw_input("Enter x:"))
y = int(raw_input("Enter y:"))

sum = x + y
print(sum)
```

example from https://pythonspot.com/python-numbers/